# functions are not being reconized in my context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

when i'm trying to call the function `logout` in my nextjs app are returning:[not a function error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdKBZ.png)

```js
  const { isAuthenticated, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
  function handleLogout() {
    logout();
  }
   <button
   className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2"
   onClick={handleLogout}>
   <Power className="text-[#5E5D5D]" />
   <Label className="font-bold text-[#5E5D5D]">
   Sair
   </Label>
   </button>
```

my authcontext:

```js
import { useToast } from "@/hooks/useToast";
import AuthService from "@/infrastructure/services/auth";
import { AuthenticateResponseDTO } from "@/infrastructure/services/auth/dtos/response/AuthenticateResponseDTO";
import { HttpStatusCode } from "@/models/http/http-client";
import { LoadingStatesEnum } from "@/models/loading/states";
import { LocalStorageKeys, SessionStorageKeys } from "@/models/storage/keys";
import { IUser } from "@/models/user";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { createContext, ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext<IContext>({} as IContext);

export interface IAuthProvider {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export interface IContext {
  user: IUser | null;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  loadingState: LoadingStatesEnum;
  setUser: (user: IUser) => void;
  logout: () => void;
  signIn: (
    username: string,
    password: string
  ) => Promise<void | AuthenticateResponseDTO>;
}

const CX_BACKEND_URL = process.env.CX_BACKEND_URL || "";

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: IAuthProvider) => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const router = useRouter();
  const service = new AuthService();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState<LoadingStatesEnum>(
    LoadingStatesEnum.STAND_BY
  );

  async function signIn(username: string, password: string) {
    const response = await service.authenticate({ username, password });

    if (response.statusCode === 401) {
      setLoadingState(LoadingStatesEnum.DONE);
      toast({
        message: "Verifique o usuario e senha",
        type: "error",
      });
      return response.body;
    }

    setLoadingState(LoadingStatesEnum.PENDING);

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case HttpStatusCode.ok:
        setUser(response.body.user);
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        localStorage.setItem(
          LocalStorageKeys.token,
          JSON.stringify(response.body.token)
        );
        toast({
          message: "Login feito com sucesso!",
          type: "success",
        });
        router.push("/");
        break;
      case HttpStatusCode.unauthorized:
        setLoadingState(LoadingStatesEnum.ERROR);
        toast({
          message: "nao autorizado a fazer login!",
          type: "error",
        });
        break;
      default:
        setLoadingState(LoadingStatesEnum.ERROR);
        break;
    }
  }

  function logout() {
    setUser(null);
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    localStorage.removeItem(LocalStorageKeys.token);
    sessionStorage.removeItem(SessionStorageKeys.registerFlow);
    sessionStorage.removeItem(SessionStorageKeys.timestamp);
    router.push("/login");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(LocalStorageKeys.token);

    if (token) {
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${CX_BACKEND_URL}/auth/session/`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token ${token.replaceAll(`"`, "")}`,
        },
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error("Not authenticated");
          }
          setIsAuthenticated(true);
          setUser({
            ...res.data.user,
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setUser(null);
          setIsAuthenticated(false);
        });
    } else {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setLoadingState(LoadingStatesEnum.DONE);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        signIn,
        logout,
        setUser,
        isAuthenticated,
        loadingState,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

i've tried rename that function and put anothers.